# Click event on AfreeChart

Tags: android, charts, jfreechart

How can we override click event of [AFreeChart - BarChart](https://code.google.com/p/afreechart/), is there any click listener available in AFreeChart to handle Bar's click event?

[Bar Chart Sample](http://afreechart.googlecode.com/svn/doc/screenshot/index.html)